# Prevent other users from reading my files

Tags: linux, debian, chmod

I have 2 users: Joe is root and Gary (normal user).  But if Gary enters '`cat /home/joe/function.php`', he can view all code with mysql password into this file.

What is the solution for disabling all files for non-root user?

If I delete read permission for others with chmod i have error 503.
Now all directory have `drwxr-xr-x`

I'm on debian 7

Thanks you

Comment: First of all, how can Joe "be" root? Set the file owner to Joe (or root) with chown, set the owning group to Joe (root) with chgrp, too. Then, set chmod ug=rwX,o=.

Comment: To all the people who voted to migrate this to U&L: this should've just been closed in place, *not* migrated.  Remember the guideline: don't migrate crap.